# Using Handlebars.js, how do I loop data using a value from the JSON file

Tags: json, handlebars.js

This is the JSON array:

```
{
"profile": [
    {
        "ID": 343,
        "gender": "female",
        "from": "Olivia"
    },
    {
        "ID": 4543,
        "gender": "female",
        "from": "Meagen"
    },
    {
        "ID": 787,
        "gender": "male",
        "from": "Aaron"
    }
]
}
```

This works and it outputs all the objects in the array...

```
{{#profile}}

{{from}} {{gender}}

{{/profile}}
```

Output will look like...

```
Olivia female
Meagen female
Aaron male
```

But my goal is to only loop those that have a gender equal to female. Something like...

```
{{#profile gender="female"}}

{{from}} {{gender}}

{{/profile}}
```

...and get the output to look like...

```
Olivia female
Meagen female
```

I've been struggling trying to find an answer for a few days. Am I missing something or am I way off track?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see two options:

1. Filter the data before handing it Handlebars.
2. Use a custom helper to deal with the logic inside your template.

The first one is pretty straight forward.

The second depends on how you want to do it. You could add an "if equal" helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('if_eq', function(a, b, block) {
    return a == b
         ? block(this)
         : block.inverse(this);
});
```

and do this in your template:

```
{{#profile}}
    {{#if_eq gender "female"}}
        {{from}} {{gender}}
    {{/if_eq}}
{{/profile}}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/NnH83/

Or you could write your own iterator in various ways:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('each_female', function(list, opts) {
    var i, result = '';
    for(i = 0; i < list.length; ++i)
        if(list[i].gender == 'female')
            result = result + opts.fn(list[i]);
    return result;
});

{{#each_female profile}}
    {{from}} {{gender}}
{{/each_female}}
```

Or a bit more general:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('each_when', function(list, k, v, opts) {
    console.log(arguments);
    var i, result = '';
    for(i = 0; i < list.length; ++i)
        if(list[i][k] == v)
            result = result + opts.fn(list[i]);
    return result;
});

{{#each_when profile "gender" "female"}}
    {{from}} {{gender}}
{{/each_when}}
```

Demos: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/E4jTs/, http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/AkZxN/

See the [fine manual](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html) on Hash Arguments if you want something closer to your proposed syntax.

Comment: For some unexplained reason I couldn't get if_eq working within the project I'm working on. But each_when was successful. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to add an `OR` condition to the results? Like if I want to check for 2 conditions to be true?

Comment: @SHT: Sure, why wouldn't that be possible? Might be a bit cumbersome in the template but you can do it.

Comment: `each_when` is really useful but doesn't include the `@last` and `@first` which I need for an `if` inside it. Any idea how to implement that?

Comment: @Jakub Haven't used Handlebars for awhile and the documentation is rather thin so I don't know. Maybe start with the [`each`](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/lib/handlebars/helpers/each.js) source and figure out how it works.